# How to perform preprocessing steps on image dataset once, so that it can be used for training and testing the model many times

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch-dataloader, image-preprocessing

I am training different networks like VGG16, Resnet, Densenet, Squeezenet etc. on image dataset.
I am performing following steps before training.

```
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
    root=TRAIN_ROOT,
    transform=transforms.Compose([
                 transforms.Resize((224,224)),
                 transforms.ToTensor(),
                 transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.541, 0.536, 0.357],
                                      std=[0.321, 0.339, 0.441])
    ]) )

test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
    root=TEST_ROOT,
    transform=transforms.Compose([
                 transforms.Resize((224,224)),
                 transforms.ToTensor(),
                 transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.540, 0.536, 0.357],
                                      std=[0.321, 0.339, 0.441])
    ]) )
```

I need to perform training many times for performing different experiments. My dataset has 30000 images, and it takes lots of time to perform these steps every time. Can I perform these steps (resizing, converting to tensor and normalizing) once and store data in another train and test folder, so that I can directly use it for training and testing.
If yes, how I can do that. (i.e. store preprocessed images and use directly for training and testing)

Answer (score 0):

You can save a tensor in the .pt format, but is it efficient? If you have large images that you resize to a smaller size, you can try it. However, if there is not a significant difference between the old and new shape, the memory usage will increase drastically because when you perform normalization, you lose the integer format. If you are using `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`, try increasing the `num_workers` so that it can process images in parallel.